# Service unavailable since initialization is not yet complete

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am using WKL7.1 on WAS8.5.5.12. 
just after installing an artifact of 10 KB, the server went out of sync.
MSite reported this error:

Service unavailable since initialization is not yet complete.

### And the console shown the initialization message.

I haven't seen any errors related to WKL runtime component. All run-time and admin services are getting initialized properly and available for service.
But I have noticed in the log that many artifacts are getting downloaded.

HttpUtil      I com.worklight.common.util.HttpUtil getBytesFromURL FWLSE2014I: Downloading a worklight artifact from https://<>/wladmin/otu/1.0/2337ffffff8223ffffffc07fffffffdcffffff955cffffff822a05ffffffd7036627/runtimes/worklight/downloads/adapters/Temporary317569284 [project worklight]

Below are the logs collected related to sync...
  FFDC Exception:javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke ProbeId:693 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1@579b0a4c
javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: java.lang.RuntimeException: @@@ Runtime synchronization in progress. Cannot return application runtime information
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: @@@ Runtime synchronization in progress. Cannot return application runtime information
    at com.worklight.twopc.runtime.RuntimeTransactionHandler.ensureSyncStatusIsOk(RuntimeTransactionHandler.java:512)
        at com.worklight.mgmt.impl.ApplicationManagementImpl.getApplicationRuntimeInformation(ApplicationManagementImpl.java:170)

### at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.getApplicationRuntimeInformation(ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.java:1395)

FFDC Exception:javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke ProbeId:422 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl@75e1a753

### javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: java.lang.RuntimeException: @@@ Runtime synchronization in progress. Cannot get devices summary from runtime

Answer (score 0):

Your runtime sync has failed. Runtime sync occurs when adapters/app updates happen. This means that the resources that need to be available to the runtimes have to be updated. That process seems to have started because you can see the artifacts getting downloaded. Are these downloads getting complete ?

Will encourage you to collect traces with the following trace spec string and open a support ticket with IBM.

trace specs : com.worklight.*=all

Don't think your issue is related to the above custom property , but this setting should be required for WAS 8.5.5.12